# Cannot insert rows for table having values and a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am a beginner in SQL and I am currently stuck on something. So I tried to insert 3 rows in admin and it worked fine. Now I want to insert 3 rows of data in data_center however when running it I got an error "column "name" of relation "data_center" does not exist" can someone explain what's happening? Thanks in advance

```
CREATE TABLE admin
(
    username VARCHAR unique,
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE data_center
(
    name VARCHAR,
    username VARCHAR,
    capacity INT NOT NULL
        CHECK (capacity > 0 AND capacity < 20000),
    PRIMARY KEY (name),
    FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES admin(username)
);

INSERT INTO admin (username)
VALUES ('Alan'), ('Bob'), ('Lea');
    
INSERT INTO data_center (name, username,capacity)
VALUES ('Alan Johnson'   'Alan'   '4000'),
       ('Bob Lane'   'Bob'   '2000'),
       ('Lea Larsson'   'Lea'   '6000');
```

Comment: Try to add `Edward` to the `admin` table too

Comment: I matched the FK values with the PK ones but I still have the same error

Comment: Please test your code after editing it but before posting it.  Your posted code does not fail with the error you indicate.

Answer (score 2):

1. Values in record need to be comma separated.
2. Capacity is `integer` value

```sql
    INSERT INTO data_center (name, username, capacity)
    VALUES  ('Alan Johnson', 'Alan', 4000),
            ('Lea Lane', 'Lea', 2000),
            ('Edward Larsson', 'Edward', 6000);
```

3. `Edward` is not in `admin` table. Edward became `Lea` between edits.